# Saving a Web page for offline viewing

Tags: internet, webview

I am using Sony Xperia Z with android 4.3. Is there any way I can save Web pages on my device to view it offline. Will it require an app? If yes, any free app for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stock Browser (the one with blue icon) from Android jellybean supports offline reading with saving web pages.. 
Menu-> Save for offline reading

Opera mini for Android also supports saving web pages
Menu-> Saved Pages-> Save

Comment: Just as a note for others reading this: `Stock browser` depends on the actual device you are using. This may be spot on for the Sony Xperia Z but it may not apply to other devices. Chrome is the new stock browser for Nexus / Google devices. Samsung 'Internet' is on Samsung devices, HTC Browser and so on.

Answer (score 2):

All the below apps are free and on [google-play-store](/questions/tagged/google-play-store)

You could use [Google Chrome BETA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta) which supports offline web pages.

[This article entitled](http://blogs.computerworld.com/android/22497/chrome-android-hidden-settings) 4 hidden settings to make Chrome for Android even better mentions this. Here is the relevant extract:

> Make Web pages accessible offline
>
> Ever surfing the Web from your phone and suddenly find yourself in a dead-zone with no connection? This next setting will let you continue to view content, provided you've opened the page before and have a cached version of it on your device.
>
> To enable it, head back into the Chrome flags section and find the option called "Enable offline cache mode." Tap enable and restart.

[From XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2178160)  Best Android browser for offline reading thread:

> [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox)  can save pages as PDF
>
> [There is Offline Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline&hl=en) which could be very useful to you.
>
> [Dolphin Browser HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) has offline support.

XDA also mentions Opera Mini and Boat Browser, but I haven't used them in many years.

Alternatively to a browser, something like  [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)  can save things for offline use, as a specific function so you can use any broswer you want!

Answer (score 0):

the best app for offline browsing: [Offline Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline).

You can save not only a single page, but also a whole portion of the site

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nossfeer](http://noosfeer.com) and make it work in any browser/OS. No need to download anything.